# How to trigger a new validation when a textbox gets enabled?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

In a wpf dialog window I have a checkbox that enables and disables a textbox. The textbox has ValidatesOnDataErrors set to True. Via IDataErrorInfo I check the value of this textbox only, if the checkbox is checked.

My problem is that if the user checks the checkbox there is no new validation on textbox performed and therefor I dont get this red frame indicating an error.

For demonstration here is a small sample:

```
<Window x:Class="Validation.ValidationWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ValidationWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsChecked="{Binding InputAllowed}">Input allowed</CheckBox>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>InputValue</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding InputValue, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" IsEnabled="{Binding InputAllowed}" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>InputValue2</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding InputValue2, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Click="OnOk">Ok</Button>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Validation
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ValidationWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ValidationWindow : Window, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public bool InputAllowed
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(InputAllowedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputAllowedProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputAllowedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InputAllowed", typeof(bool), typeof(ValidationWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public int InputValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(InputValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InputValue", typeof(int), typeof(ValidationWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int InputValue2
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(InputValue2Property); }
        set { SetValue(InputValue2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputValue2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InputValue2", typeof(int), typeof(ValidationWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0));


    public ValidationWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void OnOk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = Error;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Error);
            return;
        }
        DialogResult = true;
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { return ((IDataErrorInfo)this)[null]; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;

            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName))
            {
                msg += ((IDataErrorInfo)this)["InputValue"];
                msg += ((IDataErrorInfo)this)["InputValue2"];
            }
            else
            {
                switch(columnName)
                {
                case "InputValue":
                    if(InputAllowed)
                    {
                        if(InputValue <= 0)
                        {
                            msg += "InputValue must be greater that 0!";
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "InputValue2":
                    if(InputValue2 <= 0)
                    {
                        msg += "InputValue2 must be greater that 0!";
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            return msg;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and the validation works with me perfectly - both with the checkbox on and off I get the red border if the input isn't a number.

Comment: @tube-builder it does not work for me. Also the condition here is not a number or not, it's considered as invalid when it's ***not positive***. Try checking the checkbox, you'll see that the first textbox does not have any red border, although clicking the button shows the error message correctly. We have to change the value of the textbox (such as delete the current 0 value and re-type that value) to make it work expectedly.

Answer (score 2):

We've been using this to force validation after programatcially changing text, should work as well if you call it in reponse to your checkbox's events:

```
var binding = someTextBox.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty );
if( binding == null )
  return;
binding.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: You are right. If I put this code in the Checked and Unchecked event of the checkbox it works as expected. But this isn't very convenient, if you have complicated windows with multiple such constructs. I was hoping for an easier way, such as maybe a style (or a flag that I overlooked) that triggers validation when IsEnabled changes.

Comment: That is a bit out of scope for this question but I'm pretty sure you can use DependencyProperty to create a custom property so that in xaml you can do something like `<TextBox behav:TriggerValidation.Source="myCheckbox", behav:TriggerValidation.Event="checked"/>`. There are numerous examples here on SO, at least that's where I got a lot of my DependencyProperties :]

Comment: Interesting. Could you please provide more info on how to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the source for ACB: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/ Had a quick look at it and since it allows you to make any event invoke arbitrary commands, it's not a big step to modify it so that it calls the code in my answer instead of an arbitrary command. You'll have to add a property to get the textBox in though. If it doesn't work out, I suggest you post a different question for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

No actual difference from stijn's solution but since we're all a little lazy:

```
public static class DependencyPropertyExtensions
{
    public static bool UpdateSource(this FrameworkElement source, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        var binding = source.GetBindingExpression(property);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            binding.UpdateSource();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```